# Xamarin Custom Controller & Commands

Tags: xamarin.forms, command, custom-controls

As per a previous question [Xamarin Forms slide button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45936224/xamarin-forms-slide-button) I have a custom controller. However, it currently only has an event attached to it and I would like it to be capable to handling commands so I can apply the MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `EventToCommandBehavior` class which is part of `xamarin.forms`.

Documentation & samples here: [Invoking a command when an event fires](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/behaviors/reusable/event-to-command-behavior/)

Hope it helps!