# MAUI Swipe to Accept

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

I am trying to develop a custom control that for swipe to accept in MAUI. Can some one help me with any documentation or related controls that might help in in developing this?

[image: I need to achieve something like this]

I tried using swipe SwipeGestureRecognizer, but looks like this was not that much effective in giving me the expected full results.

Answer (score 0):

According to this old case about [Xamarin Forms slide button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45936224/xamarin-forms-slide-button), I convert the answer to the Maui:

The CustomView:

```
public class SlideToActView : AbsoluteLayout
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ThumbProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            "Thumb", typeof(View), typeof(SlideToActView),
            defaultValue: default(View));

    public View Thumb
    {
        get { return (View)GetValue(ThumbProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ThumbProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty TrackBarProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            "TrackBar", typeof(View), typeof(SlideToActView),
            defaultValue: default(View));

    public View TrackBar
    {
        get { return (View)GetValue(TrackBarProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TrackBarProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty FillBarProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            "FillBar", typeof(View), typeof(SlideToActView),
            defaultValue: default(View));

    public View FillBar
    {
        get { return (View)GetValue(FillBarProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FillBarProperty, value); }
    }

    private PanGestureRecognizer _panGesture = new PanGestureRecognizer();
    private View _gestureListener;
    public SlideToActView()
    {
        _panGesture.PanUpdated += OnPanGestureUpdated;
        SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;

        _gestureListener = new ContentView { BackgroundColor = Colors.White, Opacity = 0.05 };
        _gestureListener.GestureRecognizers.Add(_panGesture);
    }

    public event EventHandler SlideCompleted;

    private const double _fadeEffect = 0.5;
    private const uint _animLength = 50;
    async void OnPanGestureUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Thumb == null || TrackBar == null || FillBar == null)
            return;

        switch (e.StatusType)
        {
            case GestureStatus.Started:
                await TrackBar.FadeTo(_fadeEffect, _animLength);
                break;

            case GestureStatus.Running:
                // Translate and ensure we don't pan beyond the wrapped user interface element bounds.
                var x = Math.Max(0, e.TotalX);
                var y = Math.Max(0, e.TotalY);
                if (x > (Width - Thumb.Width))
                    x = (Width - Thumb.Width);
                if(y > (Height - Thumb.Height)) y = (Height - Thumb.Height);
                //Uncomment this if you want only forward dragging.
                //if (e.TotalX < Thumb.TranslationX)
                //    return;
                Thumb.TranslationX = x;
                SetLayoutBounds((IView)FillBar, new Rect(0, 0, x + Thumb.Width / 2, this.Height));
                break;

            case GestureStatus.Completed:
                var posX = Thumb.TranslationX;
                SetLayoutBounds((IView)FillBar, new Rect(0, 0, 0, this.Height));

                // Reset translation applied during the pan
                await Task.WhenAll(new Task[]{
                    TrackBar.FadeTo(1, _animLength),
                    Thumb.TranslateTo(0, 0, _animLength * 2, Easing.CubicIn),
                });

                    if (posX >= (Width - Thumb.Width - 10/* keep some margin for error*/))
                        SlideCompleted?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                break;
        }
    }

    void OnSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Width == 0 || Height == 0)
            return;
        if (Thumb == null || TrackBar == null || FillBar == null)
            return;


        Children.Clear();

        SetLayoutFlags((IView)TrackBar, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.SizeProportional);
        SetLayoutBounds((IView)TrackBar, new Rect(0, 0, 1, 1));
        Children.Add(TrackBar);

        SetLayoutFlags((IView)FillBar, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.None);
        SetLayoutBounds((IView)FillBar, new Rect(0, 0, 0, this.Height));
        Children.Add(FillBar);

        SetLayoutFlags((IView)Thumb, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.None);
        SetLayoutBounds((IView)Thumb, new Rect(0, 0, this.Width/5, this.Height));
        Children.Add(Thumb);

        SetLayoutFlags((IView)_gestureListener, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.SizeProportional);
        SetLayoutBounds((IView)_gestureListener, new Rect(0, 0, 1, 1));
        Children.Add(_gestureListener);

    }
}
```

And use it in the xaml, the Frame is replaced by the Border in the Maui:

```
<local:SlideToActView HeightRequest="50" SlideCompleted="SlideToActView_SlideCompleted" >
    <local:SlideToActView.Thumb>
        <Border HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40" StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 80,80,80,80" StrokeThickness="0" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" Padding="0">
            <Image Source="test1.png" Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40" />
        </Border>
    </local:SlideToActView.Thumb>

    <local:SlideToActView.TrackBar>
        <Border StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 40,40,40,40" StrokeThickness="0" BackgroundColor="Gray" Padding="0">
            <Label Text="Slide 'x' to cancel" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </Border>
    </local:SlideToActView.TrackBar>

    <local:SlideToActView.FillBar>
        <Border StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 40,40,40,40" StrokeThickness="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Padding="0" />
    </local:SlideToActView.FillBar>
</local:SlideToActView>
```

And the result image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Liyun Zhang. I will give a try with the above code.